# Agregar un nuevo valor a un array existente

Tags: php, array

tengo un array, que contiene otros arrays en laravel, por ejemplo

```
$franchiseList  =
array:22 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Upton-Kunde"
    "description" => "Voluptatem sed id temporibus ut unde. Incidunt veniam nobis tempora perspiciatis."
    "thumbnail" => "https://via.placeholder.com/32x32.png/0066bb?text=omnis"
    "min_distance" => 836
    "created_at" => "2022-01-12T17:06:53.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2022-01-12T17:06:53.000000Z"
    "customers" => array:1 [▶]
```

a cada array dentro del array principal le quiero añadir un nuevo valor, por el momento tengo

```
    foreach ($franchiseList as $franchise){
        $franchiseDistance = $franchise['min_distance'];
        $franchise['is_available'] = true;
        foreach ($franchise['customers'] as $customer){
            $customerDistance = $customer['distance'];
            if ($franchiseDistance > $customerDistance)
            {
                $franchise['is_available'] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return $franchiseList;
```

estoy intentando introducir esos valores "true" o "false" pero no hace nada, cuando veo el array con un dd($franchiseList); no tiene el $franchise['is_available'], cómo se lo puedo añadir?

pd: la lógica del foreach está bien, bastará que la distancia de uno solo de los customers sea menor para que dispare un false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que te refieres a esto:

```
foreach ($franchiseList as $key => $franchise){
    $franchiseDistance = $franchise['min_distance'];
    $franchiseList[$key]['is_available'] = true;
    foreach ($franchise['customers'] as $customer){
        $customerDistance = $customer['distance'];
        if ($franchiseDistance > $customerDistance)
        {
            $franchiseList[$key]['is_available'] = false; 
        }
    }
}
return $franchiseList;
```

Prueba y nos cuentas si te va bien asi. En caso contrario muestranos la estructura de $franchiseList con un `var_dump($franchiseList);` para ajustar mejor la respuesta.

Comment: gracias, lo que me faltó fue añadir un index para interceptar la key, $franchiseList as $key => $franchise y ya con eso añadir al array

Comment: Por eso te pedia el var_dump, pues no sabia si dentro tenias otra array... acabo de editar mi respuesta, mira si ahora es lo correcto en tu caso